# Logging after exception on application start

Tags: spring-boot, logging

Using Spring boot 2.0.5. On application start occurs a exception with is logged 'ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization'. But i need stacktrace. I was expecting stack trace will be logged later in SpringApplication.reportFailure '"Application run failed"'. But spring boot calls before this method ServletWebServerApplicationContext.stopAndReleaseWebServer and its seems that after this call any logging does not work anymore.

Answer (score -2):

this can be related to your issue: [spring boot discussion](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/14187)

[spring boot github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12457)

You can also debug SpringApplication#reportFailure in the end (after catch (throwable)) it has generic logging of any error:

```
logger.error("Application run failed", ex)
```

In my case I had the logger from commons-logging which prevented logging to happen.

Comment: Not sure, why the answer is downvoted.  reportFailure is a first thing to debug and check in case you don't see a stacktrace of spring boot startup error.